# Convert Long to Task<long>

Tags: c#

I am just learning about `Async` programming from a book and hehe! their example doesn't work.

Author (Adam Freeman in WebAPI2 book, Chapter 3, Page 47! ) wants to explain a technique that when we have a series of sync statements and we want to execute them `Async`. He says

> this is done by creating a starting a task that wrap around the
>   statements that we need to execute and return the Task as the result
>   from the method.

Then he says look at this example. Well Surprise! it doesn't even work because it can't convert from `long` to `Task<long>`

How am I supposed to fix this code?

```
public interface ICustomController
{
    Task<long> GetPageSize(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

```
public Task<long> GetPageSize(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    WebClient wb = new WebClient();
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    List<long> results = new List<long>();

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Making Request {0} ", i);
            results.Add(wb.DownloadData(TargetUrl).LongLength);

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled...");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed ms: {0} ", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    return (long)results.Average();
}
```

Note that he has **intentionally** removed the `aysnc` and `await` from the method so he can explain this technique..but he has forgot to actually fix his code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return Task.FromResult((long)results.Average());
```

This is how you return an awaitable result from a non-async function.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume he wanted to use `Task.Run()` to load the work of to a threadpool thread.
You can use it like

```
public Task<long> GetPageSize(CancellationToken cancellationToken))
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
         // body of the original methode
    });
}
```

And the caller than can just await the returned `Task`-object.

Read more about `Task.Run()` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8).